# What is the cost of object creating

Tags: asp.net, performance, architecture

If I have to choose between static method and creating an instance and use instance method, I will choose static methods always. but what is the detailed overhead of creating an instance?

for example I saw a DAL which can be done with static classes but they choose to make it instance now in the BLL at every single call they call something like.

new Customer().GetData();

how far this can be bad?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance penalty should be negligible. In [this blog entry](http://elegantcode.com/2008/08/21/c-object-creation-time-trials/) someone did a short benchmark, with the result that creating 500,000 objects and adding them to a list cost about 1.5 seconds.

So, since I guess `new Customer().GetData();` will be called *at most* a few hundred times in a single BLL function, the performance penalty can be ignored.

As a side note, either the design or the naming of the class is broken if `new Customer().GetData();` is actually used: If class `Customer` just provides the means to get the data, it should be called something different, like `CustomerReader` (for lack of a better name). On the other hand, if `Customer` has an instance state that actually represents a Customer, `GetData` should be static -- not for reasons of performance, but for reasons of consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Normally one shouldn't be too concerned about object creation overhead in the CLR. The allocation of memory for the new object would be really quick (due to the memory compacting stage of the garbage collector - GC). Creating new objects will take up a bit of memory for the object and put a bit more pressure on the GC (as it will have to clean up the object), but if it's only being used for a short time then it might be collected in an early GC generation which isn't that bad performance wise. Also the performance overhead would be dwarfed by the call to a database.

In general I'll make the decision whether to create a new object for some related methods or just utilize a static class (and methods) based on what I require from the object (such as need to mock/stub it out for tests) and not the slight difference in performance

As a side note - whether `new Customer().GetData();` is the right place to put such code is questionable - to me it seems like the Data returned is directly related to a customer instance based on that statement and not actually a call to the database to retrieve data.